# How to place an array as value of a key in another array using nodeJs?

Tags: arrays, node.js

i have an array like this :

var a = [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), …];

i want to add this array as a value to another array like :

var resultArray = {};

resultArray = [key : a];

how can i achieve this..please help me since i am new in this technology

Comment: `var resultArray = [key : a];` is not legal.  Arrays contain single entries as their array entries, not key/value pairs.  You can use a key/value pair with an object as in `resultArray[key] = a;`.  Or you can put one array into another as an entry as in `resultArray[2] = someOtherArray;`.  But we can't tell what problem you're really trying to solve so it's hard to help more directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
var resultArray = {};

resultArray.key = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to concatenate a few arrays to a single array. The best solution for this can be:

```
var resultArray = [];
for(var arr of a){
    Array.prototype.push.apply(resultArray,arr);
}
```